# Change variable in-place

Tags: python, pass-by-reference

I want to be able to modify a variable. F.e. :

```
b = 0
setbit(b,4)
```

I expect b to become 16.
But as we know python is pass-by-assignment, not pass-by-value or pass-by-reference.
My question is : Is this possible in some other way ?

The best shortcut I've come up with is :

```
def nbit(n) : return 1 << n
```

and then :

```
b |= nbit(4)
```

I would prefer a function like the first example.

Comment: A function like the first example isn’t possible. I’d use `b |= 1 << 4`.

Comment: If you are willing to convert `b` into a one-element list (`b=[0]`), then you can do `def setbit(b,n) : b[0]|=1 << n`.

Comment: Python _is_ pass-by-reference.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: *Python is pass-by-value.

Comment: @Ryan - ...of the reference.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Yeah. Just trying to avoid confusion with other languages that have the same pass-by-value semantics but also an option to pass by reference, like C# and VB.NET.